# TextView tint on AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I made a few checkboxes and radio buttons with textviews, but they don't get tinted pre-Lollipop.

My textviews extend `AppCompatCheckedTextView`, are styled as:

```
<style name="CheckBoxStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:drawableRight">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple</item>
    <item name="android:drawableEnd">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
</style>
```

and I have my accent defined in my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Platform.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/press_overlay_dark</item>
    <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@style/BorderlessButton</item>

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
</style>
```

I'm building against v21, with a minimum of v16 and using AppCompat v7-22.1.1. My activities extend AppCompatActivity

[image: Genymotion 4.1.1]
[image: Nexus 5 5.1.1]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I get tint working pre-lollipop. AFAIK, it should tint along with `EditText` and the like. Added screenshots for clarification.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35867517/2826147) for update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the source for `AppCompatCheckedTextView` I've finally figured it out. **It only tints the `checkMark`**. Since it derives from `CheckedTextView`, which derives from `TextView`, `drawableRight` only gets tinted on lollipop. Looking at the source for `AppCompatTextView`, it only provides a backwards compatible `textAllCaps`. **So AFAIK, there is no built-in way to tint `drawableRight` and the like pre-lollipop.** If you want a more customizable solution, you might need to put your drawables in a layout.

The updated style:

```
<style name="CheckBoxStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item>
    <item name="android:checkMark">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 32):

For **Api level 23 >=** `android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"`

For **Api level < Api level 23** :

**JAVA**

```
private void setTextViewDrawableColor(@RecentlyNonNull TextView textView,@ColorRes int color) {
        for (Drawable drawable : textView.getCompoundDrawables()) {
            if (drawable != null) {
                drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(getColor(color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
            }
        }
    }
```

**USE:** `setTextViewDrawableColor(txtMyDemoText,R.color.colorPrimary)`

---

**Kotlin Extension Function**

```
  fun TextView.setDrawableColor(@ColorRes color: Int) {
          compoundDrawables.filterNotNull().forEach {
              it.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(getColor(context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        }
   }
```

**USE :** `txtMyDemoText.setDrawableColor(R.color.colorPrimary)`

Comment: fun TextView.setDrawableColor(@ColorRes color: Int) {
    compoundDrawablesRelative.filterNotNull().forEach {
        it.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    }
}

Comment: I tried the Kotlin approach, it didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

For API 23 and up, just set it in your layout: `android:drawableTint="@color/custom_color"`

If you need backward compatibility, you will need to set it programmatically. In Kotlin, you can create an extension function like:

```
fun TextView.setDrawableColor(@ColorRes color: Int) {
    compoundDrawables.filterNotNull().forEach {
        it.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(getColor(context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    }
}
```

And use it like: `textView.setDrawableColor(R.color.custom_color)`

*Please note that `filterNotNull()` is very important here since the list of drawables will likely have some null values (for all the TextView drawables that have not been set).*

Comment: How does it differ from the top answer?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a backward compatible TextView.

Usage:

```
<com.github.mrezanasirloo.TextViewCompatTint
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_comment_black_14dp"
    app:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:text="28"
    />
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/MRezaNasirloo/110310338c81ce1f90c8eb9a828b6c88)

Answer (score 5):

Not a direct answer to the solution. However, if you are using data binding and want to add the drawable tint. Check out the following sample: Tested on latest versions but should also work on Api <=21

```
  @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter(value = ["app:drawableStart", "app:drawableStartTint"], requireAll = true)
    fun setDrawableStartTint(textView: TextView, @DrawableRes drawable: Drawable, @ColorInt color: Int) {
        val mutatedDrawable = drawable.mutate()
        mutatedDrawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mutatedDrawable, null, null, null)
    }
```

Usage:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World"
    app:drawableStart="@{@drawable/ic_demo}"
    app:drawableStartTint="@{@color/color_demo_tint}"
 />
```

Comment: I had to change `MULTIPLY` to `SRC_IN`

Comment: Yes, that probably the case both modes are different and behave differently. Hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

The widget tinting in AppCompat works by intercepting any layout inflation and inserting a special tint-aware version of the widget in its place.if you  have your own custom version of the widget , which in your case is the checkedtextview , the tinting wont work

From developers blog under widget tinting

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

When running on devices with Android 5.0, all of the widgets are tinted using the color theme attributes we just talked about. There are two main features which allow this on Lollipop: drawable tinting, and referencing theme attributes (of the form ?attr/foo) in drawables.

AppCompat provides similar behaviour on earlier versions of Android for a subset of UI widgets:

Everything provided by AppCompat’s toolbar (action modes, etc)

EditText

Spinner

CheckBox

RadioButton

Switch (use the new android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat)

CheckedTextView

**You don’t need to do anything special to make these work, just use these controls in your layouts as usual and AppCompat will do the rest (with some caveats; see the FAQ below).**

Comment: Well, I use AppCompatCheckedTextView and it still doesn't tint. Or will it only tint if I let the activity inflate the view?

Comment: Yes just add the appcompattextview in your XML layout instead creating a custom layout extending the appcompattextview

Comment: Any example on how to proceed with "referencing theme attributes (of the form ?attr/foo) ". Ive spent 2 days attempting to get this working with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I have a tint problem. AppCompatTextView doesn't have tint effect when running on SDK below 21. My solution is setting tint color through java. 
Example below works.

xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvInfor2"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_style_black_border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

java

```
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion <= 21){
        tvInfor2.setSupportBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In ***kotlin***:

```
fun TextView.setDrawableTintColor(colorRes: Int) {
  for (drawable in this.compoundDrawablesRelative) {
    drawable?.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(getColor(context, colorRes), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
myTextView.setDrawableTintColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I had to use `drawable.tint(context, colorId)`  instead of the `colorFilter`

Comment: It requires API 17 (however didn't test).

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the top answer it would be an extension in Kotlin (but I didn't check):

```
fun TextView.setDrawableColor(@ColorRes color: Int) {
    val colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(getColor(context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    compoundDrawables.filterNotNull().forEach {
        it.colorFilter = colorFilter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Among all the solutions, which do not work for me, I have created the following:

**JAVA:** Compatible Api < 23

```java
private void setTextViewDrawableColor(@RecentlyNonNull TextView textView,@ColorRes int color) {
        for (Drawable drawable : textView.getCompoundDrawablesRelative()) {
            if (drawable != null) {
                drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.getContext(),color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
            }
        }
    }
```

Use

```java
setTextViewDrawableColor(textView1,R.color.AccentColor)
```

**KOTLIN**

```
private fun setTextViewDrawableColor(@NonNull textView: TextView, @ColorRes color: Int) {
    for (drawable in textView.compoundDrawablesRelative) {
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        }
    }
}
```

Use

```
setTextViewDrawableColor(textView1,R.color.AccentColor)
```

**KOTLIN EXTENSION**

```
fun TextView.setDrawableColor(@ColorRes color: Int) {
    compoundDrawablesRelative.filterNotNull().forEach {
        it.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    }
}
```

use

```
textView1.setDrawableColor(R.color.colorAccent)
```

**ONLY XML API => 23**

```xml
android:backgroundTintMode="src_in"
android:drawableTint="FF0000"
```