# Changing RadioButton color on API 19 and below?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-support-library, android-support-design

So I have an app in which the user can select a color by choosing from a set of `RadioButtons`, I have used the `ButtonTint` XML attribute to color the buttons, but obviously this only works on `API > 21`/.

so my question is,

**how to change the color of the `RadioButtons` on KitKat(API 19) and below?**

I have tested a few methods from other stack overflow questions, but so far none have worked.

Answer (score 6):

Use **design support library (23.2.0 OR latest)** and **appcompatwidgets**  as below

**[Material Design for Pre-Lollipop Devices](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)** :

> AppCompat (aka ActionBarCompat) started out as a backport of the
>   Android 4.0 ActionBar API for devices running on Gingerbread,
>   providing a common API layer on top of the backported implementation
>   and the framework implementation. AppCompat v21 delivers an API and
>   feature-set that is up-to-date with Android 5.0

---

**[Android Support Library 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)** :

> The ability to tint widgets automatically when using AppCompat is
>   incredibly helpful in keeping strong branding and consistency
>   throughout your app. This is done automatically when inflating layouts
>   - replacing Button with AppCompatButton, TextView with AppCompatTextView, etc. to ensure that each could support tinting. In
>   this release, those tint aware widgets are now publicly available,
>   allowing you to keep tinting support even if you need to subclass one
>   of the supported widgets.

This tint aware widgets are now publicly available, **allowing you to keep tinting support even if you need to subclass one of the supported widget**s.

From link above,

The full list of tint aware widgets at this time is:

```
AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
AppCompatButton
AppCompatCheckBox
AppCompatCheckedTextView
AppCompatEditText
AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView
AppCompatRadioButton
AppCompatRatingBar
AppCompatSpinner
AppCompatTextView
```